# Missing parameter type for generic scan

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I can't seem to understand why my program needs explicit parameter types for this case. Using the following method:

```
trait DistTraversableLike[+T, +Repr]
  extends DistTraversable[T] {
  self: Repr =>
...
  def scan1lD[T1 >: T, That](assOp: (T1, T1) => T1)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T1, That]): That = {
    val b = bf(this)
    for (x <- group.prefixSumSeq(part, assOp))
      b += x
    b.result
  }
}
```

I try to use it on a specific implementation like so:

```
val x:DistSeq[Int] = DistSeq((0 until worldSize): _*)
val scan = x.scan1lD(_+_)
```

Which yields the following error message:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus{<null>}(x$2{<null>}){<null>})
     {<null>}
    - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus{<null>}(x$2{<null>}){<null>}){<null>}
    - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
    - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
```

group is a mixed trait using a method from FooParOps-trait (prototype implementation):

```
  def prefixSumSeq[T](part: Seq[T], combiner: (T, T) => T): Seq[T] = {
    implicit val srlz = getSerializerFor(part)
    var result = part.head
    var msg = part.reduce(combiner)
    for (i <- 0 until log2i(size)) {
      val partner = localRank ^ math.pow(2, i).toInt
      send(partner, msg)
      val number: T = rcv(partner)
      msg = combiner(msg, number)
      if (partner < localRank) result = combiner(number, result)
    }
    return (part.tail).scanLeft(result)(combiner)
  }
```

`part` is from `DistTraversable[+T]` and defined as `def part: Seq[T]`

I don't quite see why explicit parameters are needed here? Please tell me if more information is needed. The program is quite complex right now.

Comment: What are the variables `group` and `part` in the for loop in `scan1lD`?

Comment: I added a more thorough explanation

Comment: I tried simplifying your problem, but I end up with quite a few changes just to get something that compiles... Do you get the same compilation error if you are more explicit e.g. `x.scan1lD((x:Int,y:Int) => x + y)`? Could a problem be that it can't implicitly resolve the right `CanBuildFrom` since it doesn't know the type of `That`?

Comment: `val scan = x.scan1lD( (a:Int,b:Int) => a+b)` compiles and works as expected. To me it seems that it should be quite clear we need a builder of type: `CanBuildFrom[DistSeq[Int], Int, DistSeq[Int]]`, since (_+_) must be `(Int,Int) => Int`

Comment: Well, I think it could take any argument that has a + method defined that returns the same type. For instance a `MyType` with a `def +(MyType):MyType` method.

Comment: Well, it can take any argument T1 >: Int, right? The only viable option is Int.

Comment: No, `T1` is any type an `Int` can be assigned to, e.g. `Any`, `AnyVal`, `Int`, `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: But Int is the only one of those which supports +. I thought this might be taken into account? I need an idea of how I can make this work.

Comment: I think this is a limitation of the Scala type inference. For example, when having `def foo[T,T1 >: T, Repr <: Traversable[T], That] ...` and calling it, I get an error like: `inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,List[Int],Nothing] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds`, although it is *obvious*, that the first `Nothing` needs to be `Int`. I'm not getting the same error when putting the method in a Trait, but I'm suspecting that under the hood something similar happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is quite ugly (but might be acceptable):

```
implicit class Scan1lDable[T, Repr](v: DistTraversableLike[T, Repr]) {
  def scan1lD[That](op: (T,T) => T) // Note: no T1
                   (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, That]): That = {
    // snip
  }
}
```

Now, your example will work, but the following will not:

```
class A
class B extends A

def op(x: A, y: B) = x

val x: DistTraversableLike[B, ...] = ...
x.scan1lD(op _)
```

But this will:

```
(x: DistTraversableLike[A, ...]).scan1lD(op _)
```

So we add a convenience method to `DistTraversableLike`

```
trait DistTraversableLike[+T, +Repr]
  extends DistTraversable[T] {
  self: Repr =>

  def lower[S >: T]: DistTraversableLike[S, Repr] = this

}
```

And can now call:

```
x.lower[A].scan1lD(op _)
```

Granted, it is really ugly, but might be more acceptable than having to specify the method types.